# VBA runtime error 13 type mismatch when executing for loop to replace cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following code in VBA:

```
Sub creditformat()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

`
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1")

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
**If ws.Cells(i, "AC").Value = "N.A" Then**
        ws.Cells(i, "AC").Value = "Unrated"
    End If
    
Next i
End Sub`
```

The line between two asterisks is the one causing issues. Does anyone know how to resolve this? I thought it should be a fairly simply script, but somehow it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

I've also tried defining a range, like

```
Set rng = ws.Range("AC2:AC" & lastrow)

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "N.A" Then
        cell.Value = "Unrated"
    End If
    
Next cell
```

But it doesn't work as well

Comment: If the error is a type mismatch then it probably means just that: there's a mismatch between the value you are checking and the "N.A". What does the workbook look like?

Comment: The cells aren't formatted so it's just in the General excel format. It's populated with various credit ratings like "AAA or equivalent" etc. The thing is I tried it in another workbook and it works, but not in this so it's quite strange

Comment: Try `If IsError(cell.Value) Then` because "N.A" is only the visibility of the error type.

Comment: Hey, actually it's not an excel formula error the cell's value is N.A haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible scenarios here in my opinion:

**1.** You are trying to check whether the `ws.Cells(i, "AC").Value` is an error.

In this case, Black cat's suggestion is correct, you must use IsError like so:

```vb
Sub creditformat()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1")

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If IsError(ws.Cells(i, "AC").Value) Then
        ws.Cells(i, "AC").Value = "Unrated"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

**2.** You are actually attempting to compare against the "N.A" string but some of the cells in your range have errors in them (which you don't care about), which causes the type mismatch. In this case, some error handling is needed. Try this:

```vb
Sub creditformat()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1")

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    On Error GoTo skip
        If ws.Cells(i, "AC").Value = "N.A" Then
            ws.Cells(i, "AC").Value = "Unrated"
        End If
skip:
    On Error GoTo -1
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this is it! I didn't realise errors in cells would cause the macro to break.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest breaking out the code that causes the error into a separate procedure, so, add this to the same Module that your `creditformat` procedure is in (or another standard Module):

```
Function IsCellNA(cel As Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsCellNA = cel.Value = "N.A"
End Function
```

... this will return True if the cell contains a text value of "N.A" and False for any other value but the key things here are:

- It still returns False if the test of the value results in an error (which it could be if the cell itself contains an error code)
- If the test results in an error, that error is suppressed within this procedure and the calling (ie the `creditformat` procedure) code can continue running to conclusion

Then adjust the `If ws.Cells(i, "AC").Value = "N.A" Then` line to call this newly-added function, eg `If IsCellNA(ws.Cells(i, "AC")) Then`